# Problema con procesos C#

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un launcher para un juego. La cosa es que el juego funciona si le doy click a un archivo .bat y esta llama a un archivo `.ini` para sus parámetros, pero dentro del archivo `.ini` el debe de ejecutar otro proceso para que inicie el juego. pongo los códigos.

Archivo BAT

```
start "" "C:\DayZ\Steam\steam_loader.exe" !Start_client_parameters.ini
```

Archivo INI

```
Target = DayZ_x64.exe
StartIn = C:\DayZ
CommandLine = -name=nombreUsuario -connect=0.0.0.0 -port=2313 "-mod=C:\DayZ\Mods\@Trader;"
SteamClientPath = C:\DayZ\Steam\steam_emu.dll
SteamClientPath64 = C:\DayZ\Steam\steam_emu.dll
Persist=0
ParanoidMode=0
InjectDll=0
```

Estas instrucciones funcionan, pero no es lo indicado ya que los usuarios ven la secuencia y tienen acceso a la ip del servidor y sus puertos y mas datos importantes. Para esto estoy creando un launcher en visual C#.
Ya que están contextualizados les explico estoy intentando hacer lo mismo, pero en visual c# con este código

```
StartEmmu.StartInfo.FileName = startEmmu;//ruta del ejecutable es igual al que esta dentro del bat C:\DayZ\Steam\steam_loader.exe
StartEmmu.StartInfo.Arguments = dayzStart;//argumentos del ini
StartEmmu.Start();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que ocurre es que el `steam_loader.exe` necesita la ruta del `DayZ_x64.exe` pero cuando se ejecuta dice que no encuentra el target osea que no puede ejecutar el `DayZ_x64.exe` por qué no lo encuentra.
Si alguien me puede dar un poco de información para poder continuar se los agradecería.

Comment: Como le estás asignando el valor a la variable startEmmu?, puede ser un problema con el caracter "\" en la cadena, pues en c# el slash dentro de una cadena representa una secuencia de escape, dicho simple no lo reconocerá

Comment: `string dayzStart = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\DayZ_BE.exe\n";` esta es la manera que le estoy dando la ubicacion.

Comment: Los caracteres *\n* al final de cadena dayzStart creo que sobran.